# Erro ao imprimir lista estática

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Como eu faço para imprimir a minha lista estática?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 3

struct alunos {
    int matricula;
    char nome[30];
    float nota1, nota2;
};

typedef struct lista {
    int quant;
    struct alunos dados[MAX];

} Lista;

Lista* cria_Lista() {

    Lista* l;
    l = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));

    if(l != NULL)
        l->quant = 0;

    return l;
}

void libera_Lista(Lista* l) {
    free(l);
}




int insere_final(Lista* l, struct alunos al) {

    if(l == NULL || lista_Cheia(l))
        return 0;

    l->dados[l->quant] = al;
    l->quant++;

    return 1;
}

int insere_inicio(Lista *l, struct alunos al) {

    if(l == NULL || lista_Cheia(l))
        return 0;

    int i;
    for(i= l->quant - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        l->dados[i + 1] = l->dados[i]; //proxima posicao e igual a atual
        l->dados[0] = al; //pega a primeira posicao
        l->quant++; //incrementa quantidade
        return 1;
    }

}

void imprime_lista(Lista* l) {

    if(l == NULL)
        return; // nao retorna nada

    int i; //variavel auxiliar
    for(i=0; i < l->quant; i++)
        printf("Matricula: %d\n", l->dados[i].matricula);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", l->dados[i].nome);
        printf("Notas: %f %f\n", l->dados[i].nota1, l->dados[i].nota2);


}



int main()
{
 struct alunos al[2] = {{3, "João", 8.45, 9.98},
  {1, "Maria", 6.75, 8.54}};

 Lista *l;
 l  = cria_Lista();

 int i;

 for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        insere_inicio(l, al[0]);
 imprime_lista(l);

 }
libera_Lista(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Está imprimindo valores vazios, creio que deve estar errado  na declaração depois do `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tinha tantos erros que nem lembro mais todos que consertei. Vou tentar descrevê-los comparando o que está na pergunta e o que ficou no meu que ainda tem vários problemas, não tentei resolver tudo, apenas fazer funcionar.

Tirei os comentários que não eram úteis e dei uma organizada e modernizada.

O erro principal na impressão é a falta de chaves no `for`. O ideal é sempre colocar chave, mesmo que não precise, assim evita erros por descuido.

A função de inserção no início não inseria nada, apenas fazia o deslocamento dos dados, que inclusive encerrava na primeira interação. Não acho que isso é o ideal e não sei se está fazendo da maneira correta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 3

typedef struct alunos {
    int matricula;
    char nome[30];
    float nota1, nota2;
} Alunos;

typedef struct lista {
    int quant;
    Alunos dados[MAX];

} Lista;

Lista* cria_Lista() {
    Lista* l = malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if (l != NULL) l->quant = 0;
    return l;
}

void libera_Lista(Lista* l) {
    free(l);
}

int insere_final(Lista* l, Alunos al) {
    if (l == NULL) { // || lista_Cheia(l)) { --- tirei porque a função não existe
        return 0;
    }
    l->dados[l->quant] = al;
    l->quant++;
    return 1;
}

int insere_inicio(Lista *l, Alunos al) {
    if (l == NULL) { // || lista_Cheia(l)) { --- tirei porque a função não existe
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = l->quant - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        l->dados[i + 1] = l->dados[i];
        l->dados[0] = al;
        l->quant++;
    }
    l->dados[0] = al;
    l->quant++;
    return 1;
}

void imprime_lista(Lista* l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < l->quant; i++) {
        printf("Matricula: %d\n", l->dados[i].matricula);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", l->dados[i].nome);
        printf("Notas: %f %f\n", l->dados[i].nota1, l->dados[i].nota2);
    }
}

int main() {
    Alunos al[2] = {{3, "João", 8.45, 9.98}, {1, "Maria", 6.75, 8.54}};
    Lista *l = cria_Lista();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        insere_inicio(l, al[i]);
        imprime_lista(l);
    }
    libera_Lista(l);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/N112EJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jakuhxdj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LinkedList.c).

Comment: a função lista cheia eu ocultei do codigo.

Comment: @user57116 Ajuda colocar tudo que dê para gente testar. Fazendo um [mcve]. Dê uma olhada no [tour] também. Pode votar em tudo o que quiser no site.